# Google Apps and Google Reader - Third level domain

Tags: rss, google-workspace

I'd like to point a third level domain (eg. reader.mydomain.com) to google reader just like mail.mydomain.com points to gmail. Is it possibile, and if yes, how would I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Reader doesn't show as service in Google apps. It doesn't have special URL like Mail has `http://mail.google.com/a/<domain>`. If you try `reader.google.com/a/<domain>`, it'll be exactly equal to `reader.google.com` (i.e., the user will use whatever logged in account, either Gmail or Google Apps, or be asked to enter one, like normal Gmail does, not like the Gmail Apps login page).

Having said that, you can make domain `reader.domain.com` redirect to `reader.google.com`, but it doesn't gain anything additional, unlike mail one does for example.